# Get end position of element. The position when the animation is finished. In OOP Javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate, position

I want to get the end position of my object. So the top and left position when the animation is done. I want to get that position directly not after the animation is finished.

I want to do this Object Oriented.

This is what i got:

```
(function($) {

    Block = function() {

        this.el = $('<div></div>');
        this.el.css('position', 'relative');

        }

    Block.prototype.appendTo = function(parent) {

         this.el.appendTo(parent);
         return this;
    }

    Block.prototype.setSize = function(w, h) {

         this.el.css('width', w); 
         this.el.css('height', h);
         return this;    
    }

    Block.prototype.setPosition = function(x, y, speed) {

        speed = speed || 0;
        this.el.animate({'left': x+ 'px', 'top': y+ 'px'}, speed);
        return this;
    }

    Block.prototype.getPosition = function() {

        var left = this.el.position().left;
    var top = this.el.position().top;
    return [left, top];
    }



})(jQuery);
```

When i make a block with this Class and console.log the position, then i get the position of the starting point of the block. I want to get the end position. Directly

```
var block1 = new Block
block1.appendTo('body')
        .setSize(100,50)
        .setPosition(200, 300, 3000);


console.log(block1.getPosition());
```

So console.log = `[0, 0]` i want it to be `[200, 300]`

Comment: Why would you want to do that? Just get the position after the animation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `data()` to store data related to the element:

```
(function($) {
    Block = function() {
        this.el = $('<div></div>');
        this.el.css('position', 'relative');
    }

    Block.prototype.appendTo = function(parent) {
         this.el.appendTo(parent);
         return this;
    }

    Block.prototype.setSize = function(w, h) {
         this.el.css({width: w, height: h}); 
         return this;    
    }

    Block.prototype.setPosition = function(x, y, speed) {
        speed = speed || 0;
        this.el.data({top: y, left: x}).animate({'left': x+ 'px', 'top': y+ 'px'}, speed);     return this;
    }

    Block.prototype.getPosition = function() {
        return [this.el.data('left'), this.el.data('top')];
    }
})(jQuery);
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/xGXD8/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You only can store the designated position when calling `setPosition`, and retrieve that instead.

```
Block = function() {
    this.el = $('<div></div>').css('position', 'relative');
    this.position = null;
};
Block.prototype.setPosition = function(x, y, speed) {
    this.position = {'left': x, 'top': y};
    this.el.animate(this.position, speed || 0);
    return this;
};
Block.prototype.getPosition = function() {
    var pos = this.position || this.el.position();
    return [pos.left, pos.top];
};
```